# Apigen Netbeans

Tags: documentation

I tried used apigen for generate documentation from netbeans i followed all steps from page but when i do this i found a file.txt with things that i do not understand.

I did not find a file.html with the documentation. Please help me.

Comment: A couple things to address here: First, is this QA related? Or just general `apigen` related? If it's general `apigen` we'll want to move it to a more appropriate site. If it's QA related, could you describe that relationship? Second, you'll need to be more specific about what you did, what the result was. I suspect this belongs on another site, but none of the other sites would be willing to take it in its current form.

Comment: I am looking generate a documentation of my project and i read about apigen in netbeans, i just want to do the documentation about all class and functions of my project. Thanks @corsiKa

Comment: @corsiKa i did download phah from the page and made the .bat then on neatbeans:
option-> php->frameworks->apigen and picked the .bat